# Next.js Image – Set format for specific img / url

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image, image-optimization

The Next.js image component is normally choosing the best possible format for an images (avif, webm etc.) by accepted format-types of the browser.
In my case i need to have the best possible format (avif) for most images except some gallery images that need to be jpeg.

I tried to set the format (jpg) for a specific image/url but nothing worked yet.

Is there a possibility to specify the format.
Like a query for the optimization "/_next/image?url=" + img-url + "?fm=jpg" or something like that?
Or a special way in the next/config?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [custom loader](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader) for images that need to be in a specific format. If you combine this with a service like [Imgix](https://imgix.com/solutions/compression-and-performance) you can still request specific image sizes/crops/etc for your assets.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `unoptimized` setting that can be configured globally or per image (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#unoptimized).

Comment: With this option next is not generating new sizes. I am more looking for a solution that is still generating new images with specified width, quality and format.